# How does dynamic linker changes text segment of process?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, dynamic-linking

If i understand correctly when user tries to execute dynamically linked
executable (with `execve("foo", "", "")`) instead of loading text segment of "foo" dynamic linker is loaded (ld-linux.so.2) and executed. It have to load
libraries required for program ("foo") to run and change some addresses 
in "foo" and pass control to foo, but how is this acomplished?

How (what system call it uses) and where 
does dynamic loader load libraries and "foo"s code and data in memory (I am guessing it can't simply use
 malloc or mmap and then jump to code since that should be impossible,
  right? It also seems unlikely that it creates temp file whith complete 
  executable (like staticlly linked one) and calls exceve again.).

Comment: "since that should be impossible, right?" Wrong.

Comment: Strange, the impossible works very well on my desktop and other computers, including mobile. You might want to do some research on your own about dynamic linking and how programs are initialised on Linux (and other modern OSs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual implementation is quite complex as it builds on top of ELF, which is quite complex as it tries to accommodate many scenarios, but conceptually it's quite simple.

Basically (after the library dependencies are located and `open`ed) it's a couple of *mmap*s, *mprotect*s, some modifications to implement the linking by binding symbols (can be deferred), and then jump to code.

Ideally, the linked shared libraries will be compiled with `-fpic`/`-fPIC` which will allow the linker to place them anywhere in the processes address space without having to write to the `.text` section (=executable code) of the library.
Such a library/executable will call functions from other libraries via a modifiable table, which the linker will fix up (probably lazily) to point to the actual locations where it has loaded the dependent library.
Access to variables from one shared library to another is similarly indirected.

Limiting the modifying library data/code as much as possible allows marking sections of code to be marked read only (via the MMU / the `mprotect` system call) and mapped into memory that's shared among all processes that use that particular library.

---

To get an idea of what happens at the syscall level, you can try e.g.:

```
strace /bin/echo hello world
```

and all the syscalls up to about `sbrk` included (=setting up the heap / `.data` segment) should be the doings of the dynamic linker.

---

(`malloc` is indeed unavailable to the linker as `malloc` is a feature of the c library, not the system. `malloc` is about growing and managing the heap section and potentially `mmap`ping other separate blocks and managing those as well as the writable "heap", and the dynamic linker isn't concerned about these sections of a process image, mainly just its writable indirection tables and where it maps libraries).